# Django 1.3.1 on google app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm working on a project which is (very!) out of date and still uses Django 1.3.1. The plan is to bring this up to date, but more urgently we're also looking to switch the server from a current unreliable host, to something more modern. I've had good experiences with Google Cloud Engine, and in particular app engine, and it seems like an attractive way to host now that Google also offer CloudSQL so we don't need to go the django-nonrel route.

I realise that app engine doesn't support 1.3 natively anymore (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/django) but I thought it would work by vendoring the old version of django into a `lib/` directory.

I can run this app via `python2 myapp/manage.py runserver` but when I run `dev_appserver.py app.yaml` I get the following:

```
    ERROR    2016-08-16 12:38:36,149 wsgi.py:279] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/home/jamie/work/focus/website-git/lib/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/jamie/work/focus/website-git/lib/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 168, in get_response
    receivers = signals.got_request_exception.send(sender=self.__class__, request=request)
  File "/home/jamie/work/focus/website-git/lib/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 172, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/home/jamie/work/focus/website-git/lib/django/db/__init__.py", line 101, in _rollback_on_exception
    transaction.rollback_unless_managed(using=conn)
  File "/home/jamie/work/focus/website-git/lib/django/db/transaction.py", line 133, in rollback_unless_managed
    connection.rollback_unless_managed()
  File "/home/jamie/work/focus/website-git/lib/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 193, in rollback_unless_managed
    self._rollback()
  File "/home/jamie/work/focus/website-git/lib/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 331, in _rollback
    BaseDatabaseWrapper._rollback(self)
  File "/home/jamie/work/focus/website-git/lib/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 50, in _rollback
    return self.connection.rollback()
  File "/home/jamie/work/focus/website-git/lib/pymysql/connections.py", line 711, in rollback
    self._read_ok_packet()
  File "/home/jamie/work/focus/website-git/lib/pymysql/connections.py", line 687, in _read_ok_packet
    raise err.OperationalError(2014, "Command Out of Sync")
OperationalError: (2014, 'Command Out of Sync')
```

At first I assumed this was a db level problem, but it works fine when I use the `manage.py`, so I'm unsure what to do.

Is this just not going to work because of some inherent version mismatch or am I missing something? Hoping a django / app engine expert can chime in.

In case it helps, here are the other app engine specific files:

## main.py

```
import django.core.handlers.wsgi

app = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

## app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'myapp.settings'

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

## appengine_config.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
```